# Is a single WatchService guaranteed to pick up all incoming files copied in parallel?

Tags: java, watchservice

I have started working with WatchService to monitor a directory for incoming files. When copying multiple files at the same time, the modification reports can be interlaced and look erratic. My understanding is that it will pick up incoming files sooner or later. Do you have supporting information or experience which confirms this? In other words, is it guaranteed to pick up modification of a file when it has happened?

I have put together a simple application that watches a directory for changes. 
I have noticed that large files, which may be copied over a longer period of time, will be picked up multiple times for being modified (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY). I have done a quick manual testing with several files copied in parallel and I have noticed that the modification reports will be interlaced. I will be able to check if the copying of a file is complete, so getting multiple reports for the same file is not a problem. My concern is if a file may be overlooked in this process. In one scenario of concern, very small files are copied in parallel to a very large file.

```
private static void start (WatchService watchService) throws Exception {
           while (true) {
               WatchKey queuedKey = watchService.take();
               System.out.println("New key take.");
               for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : queuedKey.pollEvents()) {
                   System.out.printf("Event... kind=%s, count=%d, context=%s Context type=%s%n",
                                       watchEvent.kind(),
                                       watchEvent.count(), watchEvent.context(),
                                       ((Path) watchEvent.context()).getClass());

               if(!queuedKey.reset()){
                   keyPathMap.remove(queuedKey);
               }
               if(keyPathMap.isEmpty()){
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
```

Here is the console printout while copying

jdevstudio11124install.exe (1.3Gb)

test.txt (4 Kb)

New key take.

Event... kind=ENTRY_CREATE, count=1, context=jdevstudio11124install.exe Context type=class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath

New key take.

Event... kind=ENTRY_MODIFY, count=1, context=jdevstudio11124install.exe Context type=class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath

New key take.

Event... kind=ENTRY_MODIFY, count=1, context=log Context type=class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath

New key take.

Event... kind=ENTRY_CREATE, count=1, context=test.txt Context type=class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath

New key take.

Event... kind=ENTRY_MODIFY, count=1, context=test.txt Context type=class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath

New key take.

Event... kind=ENTRY_MODIFY, count=1, context=test.txt Context type=class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath

New key take.

Event... kind=ENTRY_MODIFY, count=1, context=log Context type=class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath

New key take.

Event... kind=ENTRY_MODIFY, count=1, context=jdevstudio11124install.exe Context type=class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath

Comment: Has anything given you reason to believe some paths are being skipped?

Comment: @VGR: The small file is picked up three times as modified, while the large file is being copied. This indicates to me that the large file is using up resources to the extent of slowing down the copying of a small file considerably. I understand that this is an event-based implementation, so I was wondering if it could happen that an event is missed because of resources taken up for another task. Or the implementation is such that it guarantees that any relevant change (such as StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_CREATE) is picked up at least once.